# Azure Event hubs for Kafka : Attempt to join group failed due to unexpected error

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, azure-eventhub

I'm facing an issue related to Azure Event Hubs for Kafka.

I have a Kafka consumer processing a message topic name "ABC" that has the below config:

**ConsumerConfig values:**

```
allow.auto.create.topics = true
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [xxxx-eventhubs-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
client.id = consumer-XXXGroupConsumer-3
client.rack = 
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = XXXGroupConsumer
group.instance.id = null
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 52428800
max.poll.interval.ms = 2147483647
max.poll.records = 1000
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 120000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = PLAIN
security.protocol = SASL_SSL
security.providers = null
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 100000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.engine.factory.class = null
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
ssl.keystore.location = null
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class KafkaConsumerDeserializer
```

Consumer is able to subscribe to topic "ABC" , but it fails with the below error:

> "Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error in join group response: The request timed out."

```
[pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-XXXGroupConsumer-3, groupId=XXXGroupConsumer] Subscribed to topic(s): ABC
[pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-XXXGroupConsumer-3, groupId=XXXGroupConsumer] Discovered group coordinator xxxx-eventhubs-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
[pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-XXXGroupConsumer-3, groupId=XXXGroupConsumer] (Re-)joining group
[pool-2-thread-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-XXXGroupConsumer-3, groupId=XXXGroupConsumer] **Attempt to join group failed due to unexpected error: The request timed out.**
[pool-2-thread-1] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator - [Consumer clientId=consumer-XXXGroupConsumer-3, groupId=XXXGroupConsumer] **Join group failed with org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Unexpected error in join group response: The request timed out.**
```

Comment: Does it work with a different topic ? 
can you connect to the same namespace using any other test console app just for testing ?
what is the network flow from A to B is there any firewall in the middle ?

Comment: Also running into the same issue - any progress so far?

Comment: I've seen this error too, and it seems to be unrecoverable - we ended up with a consumer that was just sat there doing nothing for days before we spotted the problem. Any progress? Is there anyway to handle this? If this could be detected and allow the app to reinitialize the consumer then this would be good - or automatically re-attempt to join